# Retain PVC when jenkins job is completed

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking to retain PVC when the jenkins job is completed.

```
podTemplate(workspaceVolume: dynamicPVC(requestsSize: "1Gi",storageClassName: 'test'), containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp', image: 'jenkins/jnlp-slave:3.35-5-alpine', args: '${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}')
], yaml:'''
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
''') {

    node(POD_LABEL) {
        container(name: 'jnlp') {
            sh 'echo .....'

        }
    }
}
```

and My test storage class definition

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
    name: test
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
    type: pd-ssd
```

Everything works fine. But PVC is deleted when job is completed. 
Is there any way to retain the pVC.

Comment: you have a command which is deleting it maybe?

Comment: No. I am running jenkins helm on k8s

Comment: Can you describe your PV ? Does it have reclaimPolicy: Retain too ? Also can you describe PVC ? With the “Retain” policy, if a user deletes a PersistentVolumeClaim, the corresponding PersistentVolume is not be deleted. Instead, it is moved to the Releasedphase, where all of its data can be manually recovered.

Answer (score 0):

you can't today, the PVC is created with an owner reference to the pod, so when the pod is deleted the PVC is deleted too. A new option would be needed

https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/csanchez/jenkins/plugins/kubernetes/volumes/workspace/DynamicPVCWorkspaceVolume.java#L95